# Compare two lists of coordinates and output the difference

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of coordinates which should have some overlap (within a certain range) and I'm trying to output a new list which contains all of the coords which are contained in one list but not the other. See first image below for plot of these lists.

Points in each list might be slightly different so I'm allowing for a small amount around each point.

[image: Image showing All_points (White circles) and Initial_points (orange crosses)]

So far I have something like what's shown below which outputs the opposite of what I want - all of the points which are the in common between the two lists.

```
range = 0.33

different_points = [[],[]]
        for i in range(len(All_points[0])):
            for j in range(len(Initial_points[1][0])):
                if Initial_points[0][j] - range <= All_points[0][i] <= Initial_points[0][j] + range and Initial_points[1][j] - range <= All_points[1][i] <= Initial_points[1][j] + range:
                    different_points[0].append((All_points[1][0][i]))
                    different_points[1].append((All_points[1][1][i]))
```

[image: Image showing different_points]

I'm struggling how to find the opposite list or if there's a much simpler way of doing this as a whole which I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). In particular, `intersection` and `difference`.

Either it will help you, or I misunderstood your question completely.